# Resubmit form after Ajax call returns error

Tags: javascript, ajax

Cannot resubmit the form without clicking twice when an error is returned from my api (like 'unknown user'). I want the user to be able to resubmit data but the form won't submit unless clicked twice. The firs click removes the error alert and the second click resubmits the form. FYI: `Using jquery.validate.js`

```
var validator = $('#form1').validate({
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        $('#login').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $.ajax({
            xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                login: 1,
                UserName: $('#UserName').val(),
                Password: $('#Password').val()
            },
            url: apiBase + 'login.php',
            success: function (resp) {
                window.location.replace("index.php");
            },
            error: function (resp) {
                err = JSON.parse(resp.responseText);
                $('#err').toggleClass('hidden').text(err.alert);
                $('#login').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you share a live example? This would make it easier for us to debug your code.

Comment: only on localhost right now (late ALPHA)

Comment: A simple demo will do

Comment: I will try to get something up today.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, to disable the submit button of the form, you can use the

```
onsubmit: false option of the validator ( $("#form1").validate({
  onsubmit: false
}); )
```

. Secondly, why are you passing a new validator to the "validator" variable?
Thirdly, the `submitHandler` function `triggers` after the form has been validated and also replaces the default submit button, which makes me think that `$('#login').attr('disabled', 'disabled');` is a bit of an overkill.

Also, in respect to the fact that you are clicking the button twice to get it to work, it might be a case of "too much recursion". Please refer to: https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/ too much recursion.

Lastly, I think that you should not be writing your own `ajax` call, instead use the `$(form).ajaxSubmit();` function with a `callback` option object for handling responses. Please refer to: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#options-object for more info.